# How to create InputBox (Input Text Box ) in Visual C++ (C++/CLI)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have C++/CLI project. I need compent like inputbox. I have read that I should create it by myself, but I am newbie, and haven't enough knowledge to do this. Maybe someone have working code or please explain how could I create this component . 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx

Comment: Thx for answer where should I pass this code, I have tried to put in in mainform public , but it doesn't work.